# Single Product Image not showing

Tags: zen-cart

I have added multiple products in my zen cart store. The problem is when i click on a specific product, the image wont show. It remains blank.

```
http://www.fmchase.com/
```

Above is the url of the site. When we go to a single product, i image of that product is not displayed, though it is displayed on the category.

Answer (score 0):

The image it's looking for doesn't exist.

e.g http://www.fmchase.com/images/large/Aquafresh%20little%20Teeth%20toothbrush_LRG.jpg

returns a 404 (not found) error.

edit:  The category page is using a different image http://www.fmchase.com/images/Aquafresh%20little%20Teeth%20toothbrush.jpg

Comment: yes, I saw that. How can i change the broken image to a real or correct image path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your new template.  Go to `includes/templates/your_template/templates/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php` and change all variables matching `$products_image_medium` to $products_image

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed
Content-Security-Policy module from .htaccess
and I got my listing images back